# .htaccess 301 redirects for part of url

Tags: apache, .htaccess, redirect

I am redesigning my website and in the process restructuring some of the linking structure.

To do the permanent redirects I am using the following code (.htaccess)

```
RedirectMatch permanent old-link($|\.html) http://thedomain.com/new-link.url
```

I am using a CMS and changing the link for a category changes the path of the url like so:

```
thedomain.com/old-category-link/old-article-url.html
```

to

```
thedomain.com/new-category-link/old-article-url.html
```

How should I code (.htaccess) the redirect of any URL that has

```
thedomain.com/old-category-link
```

(i.e

```
thedomain.com/old-category-link/old-article.html
thedomain.com/old-category-link/old-article-2.html
thedomain.com/old-category-link/old-article-999.html
```

)

to

```
thedomain.com/new-category-link/any-articles-old-url.html
```

Thank you

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Not exactly sure what you are asking to be redirected to, but is it something like this?

```
RedirectMatch permanent old-category-link(.*) http://thedomain.com/new-category-link$1
```

This will make is so if someone requests:

1. http://thedomain.com/old-category-link they will get redirected to http://thedomain.com/new-category-link
2. http://thedomain.com/old-category-link/ they will get redirected to http://thedomain.com/new-category-link/
3. http://thedomain.com/old-category-link/article1.html they will get redirected to http://thedomain.com/new-category-link/article1.html
4. http://thedomain.com/old-category-link/article50.html they will get redirected to http://thedomain.com/new-category-link/article50.html

Comment: Yes, you understood my question. And yes, your response works. Thank you.

Answer (score 1):

No answer worked for me. Here is what is working with my Wordpress site.

Example:

```
OLD URL: http://website.com/xxx/yyy/picture.png
NEW URL: http://website.com/wp-content/picture.png
```

So, I want to replace **/xxx/yyy/** with the normal **/wp-content/** path of WordPress.

Put this in your .htaccess file.

```
RewriteEngine on
RedirectMatch 301 /xxx/yyy/(.*) http://website.com/wp-content/$1
```